# Setting file extension type with Save vector features to file algorithm QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler, file-formats

Is it possible to set a file extension type in the "Save vector featrues to file" interface so the user does not have to select it everytime they run the model in QGIS. I want it to default to CSV.

[image]

I would want the "Save as type" to be set by default.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is an option "*Default output vector layer extension*" in "*Settings > Options > Processing > General*". After changing it to `csv` I expected this option would solve your problem, but unfortunately it didn't work.

I reviewed the related [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/9cbe0ddaacf0852f28f93f32e7ddf71f1fd4557c/src/gui/processing/qgsprocessingoutputdestinationwidget.cpp#L371) which is responsible for the settings in "*Save file*" dialog. According to the source code, the last extension, you chose before, should have been selected. Somehow, it doesn't work, too.

Normally, if you put the `file_name.extension` of an output file into `Output` text box in your model, you don't need to open `Save file` dialog. But you want `*.CSV` to be selected by default in `Save file` dialog.

My conclusion, based on above, is that you cannot set `*.csv` by default. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I hope you are too in the nicest way possible!